# Updating first table which column is null and the value came from the second table. Both table have the same primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have Attendance table which structure is like below, the value of each
column is came from the attendance of the first half of the day. TimeIn1 is in the morning before working and the TimeOut1 when employee have lunch break.
TimeIn2 when resumes to work in the afternoon and TimeOut2 when going home.

First half of the day goes to Attendance table.

```
AttnDate    EmpIdNo     TimeIn1     TimeOut1    TimeIn2     TimeOut2
2018-09-25  0005905     07:10:00    12:07:00    NULL        NULL
2018-09-25  0010134     07:33:00    12:03:00    NULL        NULL
```

Second half of the day, taken from the new logs.

```
AttnDate    EmpIdNo     TimeIn1     TimeOut1    TimeIn2     TimeOut2
2018-09-25  0005905     NULL        NULL        12:45:00    21:06:00
2018-09-25  0010134     NULL        NULL        12:50:00    20:35:00
```

Then I want to update the Attendance table only if the column is null, below is the final updated Attendance table.

```
AttnDate    EmpIdNo     TimeIn1     TimeOut1    TimeIn2     TimeOut2
2018-09-25  0005905     07:10:00    12:07:00    12:45:00    21:06:00
2018-09-25  0010134     07:33:00    12:03:00    12:50:00    20:35:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing an update join here:

```
UPPDATE a
SET
    TimeIn1 = COALESCE(TimeIn1, b.TimeIn1),
    TimeOut1 = COALESCE(TimeOut1, b.TimeOut1),
    TimeIn2 = COALESCE(TimeIn2, b.TimeIn2),
    TimeOut2 = COALESCE(TimeOut2, b.TimeOut2)
FROM Attendance a
INNER JOIN Logs b
    ON a.AttnDate = b.AttnDate AND a.EmpIdNo = b.EmpIdNo
WHERE
    TimeIn1 IS NULL OR TimeOut1 IS NULL OR TimeIn2 IS NULL OR TimeOut2 IS NULL;
```